# it is possible to made two overload method into single method

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin.forms, overloading

```
  public void Navigate<TContentPage, TNavigationParameter>(INavigation 
  navigation,
        TNavigationParameter navParam,
        Action<TContentPage, TNavigationParameter> action = null) where TContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        var contentPage = App.Container.Resolve<TContentPage>();
        action?.Invoke(contentPage, navParam);
        navigation.PushAsync(contentPage, true);
    }

    public void Navigate<TContentPage, TNavigationParameter,TSelected>(INavigation navigation,
        TNavigationParameter navParam,TSelected nav,
        Action<TContentPage, TNavigationParameter> action = null,Action<TContentPage,TSelected>action1=null
        ) where TContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        var contentPage = App.Container.Resolve<TContentPage>();
        action?.Invoke(contentPage, navParam);
        action1?.Invoke(contentPage,nav);

        navigation.PushAsync(contentPage, true);
    }
```

this is the two overload method I used to navigate can I use one of this and can I modify this method without having two action function  can I modify the second method in order to use in the both occasion

Comment: Whats stopping you from using second method in both scenario's? If action1 is null (scenario for 1st method) and you call the second method it should give identical results to calling first method

Comment: Can you explain it with an example how to call the function when if action 1 is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Put your optional parameters to the end of method definition. As per my observation, your second method varies by parameter such - `TSelected nav` and `Action<TContentPage,TSelected>action1=null`

I guess this will work fine:

```
public void Navigate<TContentPage, TNavigationParameter,TSelected>(
    INavigation navigation,
    TNavigationParameter navParam,
    Action<TContentPage, TNavigationParameter> action = null,
    Action<TContentPage,TSelected> action1 = null,
    TSelected nav = default(TSelected)
    ) where TContentPage : ContentPage
{
    var contentPage = App.Container.Resolve<TContentPage>();
    action?.Invoke(contentPage, navParam);
    action1?.Invoke(contentPage, nav); 
    navigation.PushAsync(contentPage, true);
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that nav would be available if action1 if not null. But apart from that yes this works

Comment: I don't think we can set null to the default T generic page parameter it should give an error.

Comment: @ish1104 try this: `TSelected nav= default(TSelected)` , do understand this need not necessarily be null, but that should not be an issue as you will not use it if action1 is null

Comment: didn't check it for nullable, modified my answer as per suggestion of @peeyushsingh

Answer (score 4):

Unless you want to use concrete types or an interface for `TNavigationParameter`, or at least `TSelected` then there is no need combining these two methods, as there is an extra [Generic type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) in the second variant and that parameter will need to be filled out anyway. You would have to create an overload (to remove it) which you have anyway.

In my opinion, keep what you have.

Yes, you can smash them into the one Method, but with the Generic type parameters you have, you will need to pass in a phantom generic type parameter, which IMO, it's confusing and a smell.

---

<sub>Also, `action`, `action1` is less-than-optimal naming.</sub>

Comment: yes, I know there has to be an overloading part.I done this for my final project so they asked to make this code cleaner and make them into one function how to do that

Comment: @ish1104 Unless you want to use concrete types or an interface for `TNavigationParameter`,`TSelected` then there is no point making this a single method. and infact the usage would be more weird then 2 overloaded methods